# Объектно-ориентированное программирование python. /начинающий/

Tags: python, ооп

Есть класс 'программист' и нужно написать внутри него метод rise(), который повышает его в должности. Почему мой способ не работает?

```
class Programmer: 

    def __init__ (self, name, prof): 
        self.name = name 
        self.prof = prof
        self.time = 0

    def work(self, time):
        self.time = time + self.time
        return self.time
    
    def rise(self):
        if self.prof == 'Junior':
            self.prof == 'Middle'
        elif self.prof == 'Middle': 
            self.prof == 'Senior'
        return self.prof

    def info(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.time}ч. {self.prof}'
```

Comment: а как вы поняли, что ваш способ не работает ?

Comment: присваивание нужно делать через один знак равенства a=b

Comment: `self.prof == 'Middle'` -> `self.prof = 'Middle'` и т.д.

Comment: @splash58 спасибо.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно вам нужно это:

```
def rise(self):
  if self.prof == 'Junior':
    self.prof = 'Middle'
  elif self.prof == 'Middle': 
    self.prof = 'Senior'
  return self.prof
```